# my computer doesn't charge; the plug on my computer doesn't work

Tags: windows-8, power-supply, hardware-failure, power

my computer NEVER works on just pure battery power. It always has to be plugged in. It always says "0% available. Not charging" but again, will work when its plugged in. Is this faulty mother-boarding? What could the problem be? How do I fix it?

Comment: Try a different battery.

Answer (score 3):

No, Your battery is just bad, Order an OEM/replacement.